# Jasig CAS store services in Database

Tags: cas

I'm trying to store the Services of my CAS in a database which actually works with the description on the [CAS website](http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/installation/Service-Management.html#persisting-registered-service-data).

But my problem is that i don't know what i have to put in the column `expression_type` for regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [RegexRegisteredService implementation](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/services/RegexRegisteredService.java)  with @DiscriminatorValue("regex").

I always use ant-matchers - they are enough for me. But you can try 'regex'.